# Number of permutations of n distinct objects when a particular object is always included in any arranegement

Tags: permutations

In this theorem I understand that if there are **n** objects and **r** number of objects are taken at a time and if any one object is always included in any arrangement then what we do is ($n-1!/r-1!$)-(i) but why in the formula are we multiplying (i) by **r**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the order matters.

After we choose $r-1$ of them out of the remaining $n-1$ iterms. We first sort the order.

After which, we still need to decide a position for the special object, there are $r$ options for the position of the object, hence by multiplication principle, we multiply by $r$.

Comment: okay, so its like we first find out all the arrangements with the **n-1** objects at remaining **r-1** positions and then we multiply by **r** so that we can get all the arrangements in which the special object is placed as in permutation the position matters and that object can be placed in r ways.